# @SqlResultSetMapping unknown columns referenced in entity mapping

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to map only certain fields to the entity object using a native SQL query :

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "CustomerEntity.findOnlyNameAndPhoneFromCustomer", query = "select customer_name, customer_email from customer",
        resultSetMapping = "nativeMapping")

@SqlResultSetMappings(value = {
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "nativeMapping",
entities = {
@EntityResult(
     entityClass = CustomerEntity.class,
     fields = {
     @FieldResult(name = "name", column = "customer_name"),
     @FieldResult(name = "email", column = "customer_email")
     }
)})})
@Entity
class CustomerEntity {
  //getter and setter fields
 @Column(name="customer_name")
 private String name;
 @Column(name="customer_email")
 private String email;
 @Column(name="address")
 private String adddress;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", name = "customer_guid")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
 private UUID guid;
 @Embedded
 private AuditFields audit;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
List<CustomerEntity> findOnlyNameAndPhoneFromCustomer();
```

**I am not trying to map all the fields that are present in the `customer` table to `CustomerEntity`, I am only projecting certain fields.**

This is giving me errors like:

```
17:44:37.841 [ERROR] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - The column name address2_6_0_ is not valid.
```

There is no column called `address2_6_0_` in my table, but there is a column called `address`, **why is the address column being renamed and referenced here ?**

I am only referencing `customer_name` and `customer_email`.

What is going on ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your query is empty! @Query(nativeQuery = true)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It is there in `@NamedNativeQuery`

Answer (score -1):

[`entities`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html#entities--) is for "mapping to entities".

[`@EntityResult`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityResult.html):

> If this annotation is used, the SQL statement should select all of the columns that are mapped to the entity object.

Therefore, you should use `classes` and `@ConstructorResult` for "mapping to DTOs".

```java
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "CustomerEntity.findOnlyNameAndPhoneFromCustomer",
    query = "select customer_name, customer_email from customer",
    resultSetMapping = "nativeMapping")

@SqlResultSetMappings(value = {
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "nativeMapping",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "customer_name"), @ColumnResult(name = "customer_email") },
            targetClass = CustomerEntity.class)) })
@Entity
public class CustomerEntity {

    public CustomerEntity() {
    }

    public CustomerEntity(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thats not what I wanted to do. The whole point of using `@EntityResult` was so that I could selectively initialise certain columns. And avoid the use of `@ConstructorResult`.

Comment: My point of contention is that there is no way to set the DTO variables without defining a constructors. Why can't I actually use some other method (for example like a setter to set the DTO values)

Comment: You can use [`ResultTransformer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos).